# union of sets and finding the value of a

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find the set of all real values of $a$ for which the following statement is true:
$$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}\left[1 - \frac{1+a}{n}, 2 + \frac{a}{n}\right] = [1, 2)$$
The answer is $a \in \{-1\}$, but i don't really understand how.
Can anyone help?

Comment: oh ya sorry my bad. its divison

Comment: it goes like this [ 1-(1+a/n) ; 2+(a/n)]

Comment: U n∈N[1 − (1+a)/ n ; 2 + a /n ] = [1; 2)

Comment: "it goes like this [ 1-(1+a/n) ; 2+(a/n)] "  Then edit the question and put that in, for gosh sake!

Comment: I've edited to clarify your intent. For future reference, here is a [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: i am sorry i didnt get it

Comment: Hint: the only way that a union of closed intervals $[x_n, y_n]$ can equal an interval that is closed on the left side (i.e. of the form $[x,y]$ or $[x,y)$) is if $x_n \geq x$ for all $n$ and at least one of the $x_n$ is **equal** to $x$. (Why?)

Comment: ok so it means in this question the left side should be greater than or equal to 1??

Comment: Yes, and for at least one $n$, the left hand side needs to be exactly equal to $1$. (Make sure you understand why this is.) That narrows down the range of possible answers to a single value.

Comment: it needs to be exactly equal to 1 because 1 is included in the range [1,2)?

Comment: Right. If any of the left hand sides are less than 1, then the union will include numbers smaller than 1, so that's not possible. On the other hand, if all of the left hand sides are strictly greater than 1, then the union can't include 1. Therefore, all of the left hand sides must be >= 1, and at least one of them must equal 1. Now you can calculate what must be true if $1 - (1+a)/n = 1$ for some $n$.

Comment: when we solve the left side for a we get a = -1. so that is why the answer is a = {-1}?? why arent we considering the right side tho?

Comment: @Bungo if we consider the left side limit, it always converges to $\ 1$ for any $\ a$.

Comment: @ManjoyDas Yes. But if we approach 1 from the left, our union will be too large (it will include points smaller than 1), and if we approach 1 from the right, our union will not be large enough (it will exclude the point 1). So we actually need the left endpoint of each interval in the union to be equal to 1.

Comment: @HawraSaif You do need to consider the RHS to confirm that $a=-1$ works for that side as well. I considered the LHS first because the LHS is the one that imposes the strongest constraint (it forces $a=-1$).

Answer (score 0):

$\ lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 - \dfrac{1+a}{n}\right)=1 $
Now  $\ 1 - \dfrac{1+a}{n}=1\implies a=-1$

$\ lim_{n\to\infty} \left(2+ \dfrac{a}{n}\right)=2 $

Also at $\ a=-1, \;2+ \dfrac{a}{n}=2- \dfrac{1}{n}\ne 2$
So for $\ a=-1$, we have $\ \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}\left[1 - \dfrac{1+a}{n}, 2 + \dfrac{a}{n}\right] = [1, 2)$

Comment: You've shown that $a=-1$ is a solution, but you haven't shown that it is the only solution.

Comment: if there were any other solutions, then it would come from the equation $\ 1 - \dfrac{1+a}{n}=1$

Comment: You haven't explained why $$1 - \frac{1+a}{n} = 1$$

Comment: That was just a check step if there was any $\ a $ which satisfied the equation. If not, then the left side would be an open interval. @Bungo

Answer (score 0):

Let $[1-(1+a)/n, 2+a/n]=[u_n,v_n]$ (which is empty if $u_n>v_n$).

Let $S=\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}[u_n,v_n].$

$(i).\;1\in S \implies \exists n\in \Bbb N\,(u_n\le 1)$  $\implies \exists n\in \Bbb N\,(1-(1+a)/n\le 1)$ $\implies \exists n\in \Bbb N\,(a\ge -1)$ $\implies a\ge -1.$ $$\text {So } \; (*)\;S=[1,2)\implies  a\ge -1.$$

$(ii).\;$ If $a>-1$ then (by elementary algebra) $u_1<v_1$ and $u_1<1,$ implying $1>u_1\in$ $ [u_1,v_1]\subset S,$ implying $1>u_1\in S.$ $$\text {So} \;(**) \; S=[1,2)\implies  a\le -1.$$

From $(*)$ and $(**)$ we have $$ (***)\;S=[1,2)\implies a=-1. $$

$(iii).$ If $a=-1$ then $[u_n,v_n]=[1,2-1/n)$ for every $n.$ $$\text {So}\;(****)\; a=-1\implies S=\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}[1,2-1/n)=[1,2).$$

$(iiii).$ From $(***)$ and $(****)$ we have $$S=[1,2)\iff a=-1.$$